# How to get audio in a textView like the notes app

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, nstextattachment

I am trying to figure out how to get the audio in a textview like in the notes app. I am currently using NSTextAttachment() to add the attachment to the textview as attributed text but I cannot seem to figure out how Apple's Notes app can bring in the audio to the note and also have the circle fill while the audio is playing. I have attached an image below. If anyone can point me in the right direction if NSTextAttachment is the correct way if there is a better way, that will be much appreciated. Thank you[image]

Comment: I don't believe the notes app is using a simple textview.

Comment: I see.. that could be my issue then I will keep researching and trying to figure it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on same things which are working for me.

I have audio file in my project bundle which. So I have written following code to convert audio to text.

```
let audioURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Song", withExtension: "mov")

let recognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer(locale: Locale(identifier: "en-US"))
let request = SFSpeechURLRecognitionRequest(url: audioURL!)

request.shouldReportPartialResults = true

if (recognizer?.isAvailable)! {

    recognizer?.recognitionTask(with: request) { result, error in
        guard error == nil else { print("Error: \(error!)"); return }
        guard let result = result else { print("No result!"); return }

        print(result.bestTranscription.formattedString)
    }
} else {
    print("Device doesn't support speech recognition")
}
```

First get audio url from where you have store audio file. Then create instance of `SFSpeechRecognizer` with locale that you have want. Create instance of `SFSpeechURLRecognitionRequest` which are used to requesting `recognitionTask`.

`recognitionTask` will give you result and error. Where result contains `bestTranscription.formattedString`. `formmatedString` is your test result of audio file.

If set `request.shouldReportPartialResults = true`, this will give your partial result of every line speak in audio.

Comment: thanks, but I don't want to convert the audio to text. I want to import the audio to the text view so when I tap play the progress line fills up. I am able to add an image but I am not sure how to get the progress bar to work.

Comment: you can take that output and save it in a variable and then get it in your notes